# Conditional Expectation of Function of I.I.D Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, independence

Let X,Y,Z    $\stackrel{i.i.d}{\sim}$ N($0$,$1$). I am supposed to find the E($2$X+$3$Y | X+$3$Y-Z =$4$)

I Tried to solve the problem by considering A= $2X+3Y$ ~ $N(5,5)$ and B=X+$3$Y-Z ~ $N(3,5)$ but I was confused when I was trying to find the joint pdf of A and B.

Kindly help as this is my first time in solving such type of problems.

Comment: The equation you have written in the first line is wrong.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks!

Comment: Please search the site for similar questions, like https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2912570/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2912909/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2952132/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3590203/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/597252/321264

Comment: @StubbornAtom, Thanks for linking the above questions. Really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are some errors:

$$A=2X+3Y\sim N(0;13)$$

$$B=X+3Y-Z\sim N(0;11)$$

Now you can derive how $A$ and $B$ are correlated and using the properties of jointly bivariate Gaussian you shoudl solve your problem finding

$$\mathbb{E}[A|B=4]=4$$

---

Furhter details:

To calculate $E(AB)$ simply use the definition

$$\mathbb{E}[(2X+3Y)(X+3Y-Z)]=\mathbb{E}[\text{expand}]=\dots=11$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the errors. But I am confused about Cov(A,B) because I need E(AB) and have no idea about their joint pdf.

Comment: @SohamGhosh: added some details to calculate covariance and thus also $\rho$. At this point, $A,B$ are  jointly gaussian and the pdf of $A|B$ is known to be Gaussian too...by the way did you forget to accept and upvote my answer?

Comment: @tommik.I understand the process fully now. Thanks!

Comment: To close the loop on this one: $E(A\mid B=4)=E(A) + \frac{\text{Cov}(AB)}{\text{Var}(B)}(b-E(B)).$ And $\text{Cov}(A,B)=E(A,B)-E(A)E(B).$ The calculation of $E(A,B)=2E(X^2)+9E(XY)-2E(XZ)-3E(YZ)+9E(Y^2)=2E(X^2)+9E(Y^2).$ Now, $\text{Var}(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)\implies 1 = E(X^2)-0.$ The same goes for $E(Y^2).$ Hence, $E(A,B)=11,$ and $\text{Cov}(A,B)=11-E(A)E(B)=11-0.$ Finally, $E(A\mid B=4)=0 + \frac{11}{11}(4-0)=4.$